# Conversation scope from Springfuse

Tags: spring, jsf-2, primefaces, conversation-scope

Has anyone tried using the Conversation scope implementation from Springfuse? [JSF2 Conversation](http://www.springfuse.com/2013/03/05/jsf2-conversation.html) Does it work well? Any use cases where it doesn't or issues encountered?

The link to browse their projects on Github is broken, but if you use their main page to generate a Primefaces, Spring and JPA project, the Conversation code is in there.

Answer (score 0):

yes. We have been Springfuse conversation for little over an year now. It is very lighweight and doesnt need Spring web flow. It may take a while to get used to it as you dont have many samples examples except the auto generated code and a blog (http://www.springfuse.com/2013/03/05/jsf2-conversation.html). But it is worth having a try.